# If String contain a certain substring

Tags: vba, excel

In my function, I'm trying to check if a certain string contains a certain substring. For very short string it works perfectly but when I have a long string with space it doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
'Linear Fluorescent
T(1) = "1x4 1l"
T(2) = "1x4 1l basket"
T(3) = "1x4 2l"

'CFL
C(1) = "can- 1 4 pin"
C(2) = "can- 2 2 pin"
C(3) = "can- 2 4 pin"

For i = 1 To 3
If InStr(Fixture, T(i)) >= 1 Then

    ERP_Lamp = "Linear Fluorescent"

ElseIf InStr(Fixture, C(i)) >= 1 Then

    ERP_Lamp = "Compact Fluorescent"

End If
Next i
```

The result I'm getting is alway : "Linear Fluorescent" or 0.
I seem to be unable to get "Compact Fluorescent" even if the Fixture is "can- 1 4 pin" it will still say Linear Fluorescent.

So the questions is : How can I check is my string is contain in my other string "Fixture" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide some example of `Fixture` where it goes wrong?

Comment: Ive just tried it with `can- 1 4 pin` and it worked ok.

Comment: Remember that `InStr` is case-sensitive.  You may have more luck with `InStr(LCase(Fixture), LCase(T(i)))`

Comment: HOw is a value getting assigned to Fixture? It sounds as if it's always something from T and never gets to evaluating from C...

Comment: @Chronocidal remember that `InStr` has a `Compare` optional parameter that defaults to `vbBinaryCompare`. Instead of `LCase`-ing the two strings, why not just provide a `vbTextCompare` parameter and make 1 function call instead of 3?

Comment: I've found my mistake. The mistake wasn't show in the code. 

my different array were not the same lenght this caused the C(4) to containt no data while T(4) did.

This made the InStr find a "" in every situation causing my problem.

Thank for your help.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Or even just put `Option Compare Text` at the top of the Module to change all the comparisons at once

Comment: @Used - You should put that as an answer then accept it so others don't try to fix your code without reading all the comments.

Comment: @Used - You can use a different loop for each array, and the `UBound` and `LBound` functions to skip that issue: `For i=LBound(T) to UBound(T)` will automatically loop through all elements of `T` whatever size you have made it

Comment: @Chronocidal yeah.. except `Option Compare` and `Option Base` have that tendency of being utterly ignored by certain APIs... IMO it's best to stick to `Option Explicit` (and `Option Private Module` where appropriate), and be explicit about string comparisons (and array base indices) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but rejigged your code in testing and added a bit, but the essence is still yours, and works fine.

```
Function ERP_Lamp(strFixture As String) As String

Dim t(3) As String
Dim c(3)   As String

t(1) = "1x4 1l"
t(2) = "1x4 1l basket"
t(3) = "1x4 2l"

'CFL
c(1) = "can- 1 4 pin"
c(2) = "can- 2 2 pin"
c(3) = "can- 2 4 pin"

strFixture = LCase(strFixture)

For i = 1 To 3

    If InStr(strFixture, LCase(t(i))) >= 1 Then

        ERP_Lamp = "Linear Fluorescent"
        Exit For

    ElseIf InStr(strFixture, LCase(c(i))) >= 1 Then

        ERP_Lamp = "Compact Fluorescent"
        Exit For

    End If

Next i

Erase t
Erase c

End Function
```